# How do i install wget in Anaconda Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I tried to follow the instructions from this website called https://github.com/conda-forge/python-wget-feedstock to install wget. However, i get the error message as shown below and i have no clue what it actually means. Is there a way to install wget from anaconda in windows 10?
[image]

[image]

Error when using conda install -c menpo wget
[image]

Comment: Your machine can't connect to the Conda package servers. Are you behind a (corporate) firewall?

Comment: @AKX yes if u say that.

Comment: @AKX so lets say if i use my own personal laptop to do it, and follow the instructions that is mentioned on my post, it will work fine?

Comment: It might work fine. Either way the problem described in the screenshots is that your machine can't connect to https://conda.anaconda.org .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the error message, you are getting connection timeout which is most probably related with your proxy configurations.

Use this command to see proxy_servers

```
conda config --show
```

If any proxy server is present, you can remove it by

```
conda config --remove-key proxy_servers.
```

It will remove saved proxy servers from anaconda configuration. Then run,

```
conda clean --source-cache
```

However if you are behind a company proxy, you have to set them correctly.

```
set http_proxy=http://username: password@domain.com:{port}
set https_proxy=https://username: password@domain.com:{port}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
conda install -c menpo wget
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I got the error message as shown in my updated post..

Answer (score 2):

Although I've used `wget` a lot in the past (in PHP, back in the olden days), it seems to me that you would be much better off adapting your workflow to use `requests` instead, if it's at all possible.

I wrestled with Anaconda for hours to try to get `wget` to install on a Win10 x64 version, and eventually I bit the bullet and refactored things to get rid of the dependency.

`requests` is no slower than `wget`, in my experience: I download very large GIS datafiles every month (totalling ~3.4GB) and the total download time is basically unchanged by the switch.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jupyter notebook and anaconda for management.
not same issue but was not able to install wget through anaconda (told the following packages is not available in the current channel)
I have used pip to install it in my virtual environment.

```
pip install wget
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
python -m pip install -U wget
```